# How check dispose in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to check dispose in all methods:

```
public class WebSocketClient : IDisposable
{
    private ClientWebSocket _socket;
    private bool _isDisposed;
    //methods
    public void SetBuffer(int receiveBufferSize, int sendBufferSize) =>
            _socket.Options.SetBuffer(receiveBufferSize, sendBufferSize); //How check dispose?
    //other methods
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _socket.Dispose();
            }
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

I added methods to check dispose and run acrion if object is not disposed:

```
public async Task CallWithCheckDispose(Func<Task> func)
{    
    if (!_isDisposed)
        await func.Invoke();    
    else
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
}
public async Task CallWithCheckDispose(Action func)
{    
    if (!_isDisposed)
        func.Invoke();    
    else
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
}
```

And use it:

```
public async Task SetBuffer(int receiveBufferSize, int sendBufferSize) =>
    await CallWithCheckDispose(() =>
        _socket.Options.SetBuffer(receiveBufferSize, sendBufferSize);
    );
```

But I think what this is not best solution
Is there other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a helper method, like so:

```
private void checkDisposed() {
  if (_isDisposed) {
    throw new ObjectDisposedException();
  }
}
```

Then, in each of your other methods:

```
public async Task CallWithCheckDispose(Func<Task> func)
{
  checkDisposed();
  await func.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Is my solution normal?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal"?

Comment: @Null Pointer Exception, your solution seems to be a common IDisposable interface implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose, so why it isn't normal?

Comment: @NullPointerException while the `CheckDisposed()` method used by @Mark Benningfield is the most commonly used approach for this it's perfectly fine to use your `CallWithCheckDispose()` wrapper for this as you seem to prefer the expression-bodied syntax over block bodies. So no, using a wrapper like `CallWithCheckDispose` is not the most *commonly* seen pattern but it's certainly a valid solution if this answers your question. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "normal" though

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I meant is it possible to improve it